# Alternatives to mincemeatpy and octopy

Tags: python, mapreduce

Briefly, octopy and mincemeatpy are python implementations of map-reduce (light-weight), and clients can join the cluster in ad-hoc manner without requiring any installations (Of-course, except python). Here are the project details [OCTOPY](http://code.google.com/p/octopy/) and [Mincemeatpy](https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy).

The problem with these is they need to hold the entire data in-memory (including intermediate key-value pairs). So even for a moderate size data, they throw out of memory exceptions.

The key-reasons I'm using them are:

1. Python.
2. No cluster installation required.
3. I just prototype, and I can directly port the algorithm once I'm ready.

So my question is: Is there any package which handles the same stuff, but not just in-memory (which can handle moderate size data) ?

Answer (score 3):

Try [PyMapReduce](https://github.com/fdouetteau/PyMapReduce). It runs on your own machine, but on several processes - so you don't need to build up master-node architecture and it have plenty of runners, for example [DiskBasedRunner](https://github.com/fdouetteau/PyMapReduce/blob/master/pymapreduce/__init__.py#L145), which seems to store map data to temp files and after reduces them.